# Spring boot project request timeout error on the production server

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I have a spring boot project that works very well on my local machine and also on our `dev` server. The project is deployed on tomcat 9 as a WAR file and using java 17. Last week the same WAR file was deployed on the `prod` server and there it always returns a timeout error. but the data is saved on the main table.

Here is my code

```
String validationStatus = parseValidateData(jsonStr, reportType);
            if (!validationStatus.equals(AppConstants.OK)) {
                return ResponseHandler.generateResponse(false, "Upload Failed: " + validationStatus, HttpStatus.OK, null);
            }

            Point point = (Point) wktToGeometry("POINT (" + reportData.getLng().doubleValue() + " " + reportData.getLat().doubleValue() + ")");
            point.setSRID(4326);
            reportData.setGeom(point);
            ReportData dbReportData = reportDataRepo.save(reportData);
            saveFiles(files, dbReportData.getId());
```

And after that, I save data to the other tables based on the `reportType` attribute. And in those tables, I save the id of the ReportData table which I get from dbReportData object.

So my question in the `prod` server is the clone of `dev` server with some more RAM assigned to it than `dev` server. If the same code works on `dev` server then why not on `prod` server?
2nd if I have something that I have to change please let me know.
I'm using postgres as the database engine.

Thanks

Comment: 1) Could you add some logging to your application? you can log  for instance what was the validationStatus, what is the point, some ciritcal parts of the dbReportData, as well operations which are happening in saveFiles() method. The log can be TRACE or DEBUG, so you can swith it off later. 2) Are you connecting to the same database? 3) What does the saveFiles method do? Do you see the effect of this method on prod machine or wherever the files are saved? 4) After you add logging  you can compare logs from dev and prod, or you can share the prod logs in your main question.

Comment: its a multipart request so in the saveFiles() I 1st check if there is any file if yes I save the file in server directory.
the code execute until this line `ReportData dbReportData = reportDataRepo.save(reportData);` and I can see data in that table.

Comment: I have checked the files directory yet. let me check it

Comment: so is your program entering the saveFiles() method? If yes could you share its body and add some logging there. After adding logging please share the console output in here.

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question then to contain all the error messages which you are seing, and state from where are they are comming. Now things are a bit unclear, because previously you were writing about timeout.

Comment: It was a third-party library from which I was getting data. That lib was taking forever to respond. Thanks for your time @fascynacja